# rails console Cloud9 - Can't open console

Tags: cloud9-ide

### ***NOTE*** - I solved my own problem. The issue was I was running the "rails console" command from the workspace, instead of of the sample_app directory.

When I try to run "rails console" in Cloud9, I get the below. All I'm trying to do is open the console - what am I missing? Thanks!

~/workspace $ rails console
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Runtime options:
...

Rails options:
...

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

```
You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
defaults values shown above in this help message.
```

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

```
This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably in the `workspace` directory. You need to be in your app's directory:

```
cd app_name/
```

or

```
cd ~/workspace/app_name/
```